# Error level analysis in Image

Tags: opencv, image-processing

How do I compute ELA for an image? I would like to get similar ELA image using opencv http://fotoforensics.com/tutorial-ela.php

As per this tutorial, I resaved the image at 95% quality jpeg image and using absDiff method to compute the difference between the source image and the resaved image but all I am getting is zero difference.

Any help on how to compute the difference between two images so as to obtain the error level just like sample images in the tutorial?

Comment: You should click on the checkbox near Eliezer's answer to select it as the official problem solver.

Answer (score 14):

The key to achieve a similar result is to use a variable value for the compression rate and a scale factor to make it easier to visualize the data.

Here's an example: we have the **input** image (*left*) and the **processed** image after some parameter adjustments (*right*):

[image] 
[image]

As expected, the region with the christmas hat presents a different compression rate from the rest of the image. This result is very similar to what *FotoForensics* presents:

[image]

With a few tweaks on this code you can achieve an even closer result. The source code of this project can be found [on my Github](https://github.com/eliezerb/OpenCVSnippets/tree/master/ELA):

**main.cpp**:

```
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector> 

// Control
int scale = 15,
    quality = 75;

// Image containers
cv::Mat input_image,
    compressed_image;

void processImage(int, void*)
{
   // Setting up parameters and JPEG compression
   std::vector<int> parameters;
   parameters.push_back(CV_IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY);
   parameters.push_back(quality);
   cv::imwrite("temp.jpg", input_image, parameters);

   // Reading temp image from the disk
   compressed_image = cv::imread("temp.jpg");

   if (compressed_image.empty())
   {
      std::cout << "> Error loading temp image" << std::endl;
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }

   cv::Mat output_image = cv::Mat::zeros(input_image.size(), CV_8UC3);

   // Compare values through matrices
   for (int row = 0; row < input_image.rows; ++row)
   {
    const uchar* ptr_input = input_image.ptr<uchar>(row);
    const uchar* ptr_compressed = compressed_image.ptr<uchar>(row);
    uchar* ptr_out = output_image.ptr<uchar>(row);

        for (int column = 0; column < input_image.cols; column++)
        {
            // Calc abs diff for each color channel multiplying by a scale factor
            ptr_out[0] = abs(ptr_input[0] - ptr_compressed[0]) * scale;
            ptr_out[1] = abs(ptr_input[1] - ptr_compressed[1]) * scale;
            ptr_out[2] = abs(ptr_input[2] - ptr_compressed[2]) * scale;

            ptr_input += 3;
            ptr_compressed += 3;
            ptr_out += 3;
        }
    }

    // Shows processed image
    cv::imshow("Error Level Analysis", output_image);
} 

int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
   // Verifica se o número de parâmetros necessário foi informado
   if (argc < 2)
   {
     std::cout << "> You need to provide an image as parameter" << std::endl;
     return EXIT_FAILURE;
   }

   // Read the image
   input_image = cv::imread(argv[1]);

   // Check image load
   if (input_image.empty())
   {
      std::cout << "> Error loading input image" << std::endl;
      return EXIT_FAILURE;
   }

   // Set up window and trackbar
   cv::namedWindow("Error Level Analysis", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
   cv::imshow("Error Level Analysis", input_image);
   cv::createTrackbar("Scale", "Error Level Analysis", &scale, 100, processImage);
   cv::createTrackbar("Quality", "Error Level Analysis", &quality, 100, processImage);

   // Press 'q' to quit
   while (char(cv::waitKey(0)) != 'q') {};

   return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Here are some nice references that were used to build this mash-up:

- [ELA with HTML5](http://29a.ch/2012/4/15/image-error-level-analysis-with-html5)
- [FotoForensics Tutorial](http://www.fotoforensics.com/tutorial-ela.php)
- [Blackhat USA '07 Paper](http://www.hackerfactor.com/papers/bh-usa-07-krawetz-wp.pdf)

Comment: Is there an already compiled windows executable of this code?
Sorry I'm a bit amateur to compile stuff but I loved the results shown.

Comment: I would love to have an executable as much as the previous guy, literally